# where is the tegra's hardware codec code in android source code(4.1)

Tags: android, hardware, codec, tegra

I want to find the hardware codec codec of tegra 3 in android source code(4.1). In the source code I found

```
// /androidos/android4.1/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx
void OMXMaster::addVendorPlugin() {
    addPlugin("libstagefrighthw.so");
}

void OMXMaster::addPlugin(const char *libname) {
    mVendorLibHandle = dlopen(libname, RTLD_NOW);

    // some code

    if (createOMXPlugin) {
        addPlugin((*createOMXPlugin)());
    }
}

void OMXMaster::addPlugin(OMXPluginBase *plugin) {
    // some code
    while ((err = plugin->enumerateComponents(
                    name, sizeof(name), index++)) == OMX_ErrorNone) {
        String8 name8(name);

        if (mPluginByComponentName.indexOfKey(name8) >= 0) {
            ALOGE("A component of name '%s' already exists, ignoring this one.",
                 name8.string());

            continue;
        }

        mPluginByComponentName.add(name8, plugin);
    }

    // some code
}
```

So, the android OS will load  *libstagefrighthw.so*  when need to encode/decode video with hardware. Since tegre 3 support h.264 hareware codec ( [link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tegra-3-processor.html) ), I want to find the code in the android OS. But I only find qcom and TI's code.

Does anyone can help point out where to find the tegra 3 hardware codec code?

Comment: It's almost certainly shipped as a 'blob' - a binary only library. Unless you have an NDA with nVidia that is.

Comment: @Marko thanks for your comment. Sorry that I didn't describe my question well. I just want to know where is the makefile that builds the `libstagefrighthw.so`. For example, for omap3 platform, the Android.mk is located in `/androidOS/Android4.1/hardware/ti/omap3/libstagefrighthw`.

Comment: Well, I wrote an example according to "Acodec.cpp" in `/androidOS/Android4.1/frameworks/av/media/libstraight`. It can work, but the decoding has a high latency(about 2~4 seconds for 640x480 resolution).

Answer (score 0):

The `libstagefrighthw` library is simply "glue" code that patches vendor proprietary media framework with `libstagefright` framework within Android. This approach is used to implement [hardware specific custom codecs](https://source.android.com/devices/media.html).

The `qcom`, `ti` code you see, is the one that got sync-ed into the "mainline" Android repository quite sometime back. For tegra-specific code, you will need to get your hands on a proper Tegra development repository. ([**This**](http://nv-tegra.nvidia.com/gitweb/) maybe?)

---

You may also want to checkout the **[Tegra3 `libstagefrighthw`](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_htc_tegra3-common/tree/cm-10.2/libstagefrighthw)** code within the CM 10.2 repo.